# Загрузка файлов в базу данных Python\Django

Tags: python, база-данных, django

Есть модель с FileField, через форму файл загружается нормально, но в базе данных не записывается. Как привязать его к БД?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

models

```
class TCRequestFiles(models.Model):

class Meta:
    db_table = 'tcrequest_files'
    verbose_name = 'Прикреплённые файлы'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Прикреплённые файлы'

tcrequest = models.ForeignKey(TCRequests, verbose_name=LABELS['tcrequest'])
name = models.CharField(max_length=75, verbose_name=LABELS['name'])

file = models.FileField(
    storage=TCRequestsFilesStorage(),
    max_length=100,
    verbose_name=LABELS['file']
)

date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name=LABELS['date'])

is_request = models.BooleanField(
    choices=IS_REQUEST,
    default=False,
    verbose_name=LABELS['is_request']
)
```

views

```
def listn(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST,request.FILES,request.user)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

        return render(request, 'tcrequests/listn.html', {'forms': form})
```

urls

```
url(r'^listn/$', views.listn, name ='listn'),
```

forms

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
"""
Форма доп. файла
"""

class Meta:
    model = TCRequestFiles
    fields = ['file']
```

Шаблон

```
<form action="{% url 'listn'%}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         {% csrf_token %}
         {{form.as_p}}
        <input id="uploadbutton" type="file" value="Browse" name="file" accept="text/csv" />
        <input type="submit" id="file" value="Upload" />
```

Comment: в django по умолчанию в бд хранятся ссылки на файл а не сам файл

Comment: если хотите хранить в самой бд то в  Django есть BinaryField, который позволяет хранить любые двоичные данные, включая содержимое файла

Comment: Имел в виду ссылку на файл.